# Error: Could not find or load main class ... in Spring Boot 1.5.9 version but not in 1.4.7

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was trying to generate a starting spring boot project from https://start.spring.io/

When I use Spring Boot 1.5.9 version to generate the project I am getting the following

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.demo120417.Demo120417Application
```

However; changing the version to Spring Boot 1.4.7 loads and runs the main class with no error.

I have actuator, security, thymeleaf, devtools, h2 in the dependency.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo120417</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo120417</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

What could be the root cause for this? I spent almost 1 day trying to figure out if I had issue with build path. Usually having red exclamation mark on the project points me to the library issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you import it into eclipse and how are you running it?

Comment: Right click and import it. I run it by just right click and run as >  java application

Comment: The red exclamation mark tells me that Eclipse has been unable to build your project. What problems are listed for the project in the problems view?

Comment: got errors but nothing related to this project. added the screenshot in the original post

Comment: You have 185 errors in the workspace and Eclipse is configured to only show 100. I’d recommend tidying things up a bit by closing projects, changing the filtering settings, etc.

Comment: I agree. It is a rough road for me to on that part. I need to spend sometime to work on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try this :

```
Right Click the project -> Maven -> Update Project
```

Then Re-run the project.

Comment: I have done that many times. I got a work around which is changing spring boot to 1.4.7 version from 1.5.9. I was wondering why this happened

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are doing it for the first time . you need to fill up the fields than leaving them to default
eg:

**Group**

```
com.myapp
```

**Artifact**

```
myapp
```

you need to fill there fields before genearting the project

Comment: Yes i am doing it for first time. Why taking the default field values matter? it is just a description. I tried it again but still the same.

Comment: usually you would supply those fields not sure what is the implemetation behind the textfields default vaule to be on the safer side fill them ,  try adding the dependencies later if it works for you . maven update like it is mentioned in above comment, good luck

Comment: Thanks, I will take your advise in the future.

Answer (score 0):

change to version 1.5.8 instead of 1.5.9
it works for me