# Spring boot application fails because it tries to load application.xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to add Spring boot to an existing and working Java web application, which uses Spring.

On starting the application such error is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.xml'
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:476)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:465)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:386)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:225)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:195)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:182)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
at com.barclays.scp.eps.fullserve.application.Application.main(Application.java:12)

Caused by: java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid system identifier: http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd
    at java.util.XMLUtils.load(XMLUtils.java:59)
```

It seems that Spring boot is trying to load `application.xml` file as it's config file, though I haven't specified anywhere that such file is required and I had previously created Spring boot apps from scratch, no `application.xml` was required.

The project is quite big, it has many dependencies, maybe that could be caused by some of them?

I have tried adding `application.xml` to resources folder, a valid empty xml file - the main exception is still the same, though the cause of it is a bit different - `Caused by: java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.` This means the `application.xml` was read this time, but for some reason - incorrect.

What could be the issue here, why this `application.xml` is required at all? As far as I understand, such configuration file should not be required in Spring boot app.

Some info about project configuration - these Spring boot dependencies are added (Spring boot version `1.5.9.RELEASE`):

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging' 
}
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

Main class launching the project is very basic (I know it will need more configuration, but one step at a time):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have spring boot parent dependency?

Comment: Seems like the root cause is - Caused by: java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid system identifier: http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd
    at java.util.XMLUtils.load(XMLUtils.java:59)

the application.xml does not have this

Comment: @pvpkiran , what do you mean by spring boot parent dependency, what exactly it is? I have added this in buildscript tag:   dependencies {
  classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE") 
    }

Comment: May be try adding same plugin as `plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.9.RELEASE'
}`

Comment: The `application.xml` it is looking for, for whatever reason, is the J2EE application deployment descriptor. Can you place all your dependencies? For some reason something is triggering/requesting that J2EE deployment descriptor is required.

Comment: On second thought... There is probably an `application.xml` generated by your IDE which is being loaded as a properties file. Property files can be either plain text and be expressed in XML. Spring can load both but only will try to load it when it exists. So I suspect that your IDE is generating an `application.xml` because you specified it to be a J(2)EE application. Or you have added additional plugins which cause that in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @M.Deinum , it is a java web application which uses Spring to handle dependency injections and rest requests. Is this considered J2EE? (as I understand, J2EE is different from spring).

Anyway, I was also suspecting that somehow that application.xml is required by some other dependency. Any ideas how to check it? Or how to check if IDE is generating the `application.xml`?

Comment: Check your output folder for the `application.xml` it is there in your output. I suspect that when you do `mvn clean install` on the command line it will work. I highly doubt that anything is requiring an `application.xml` because that is file being read by a JEE server not application frameworks.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thank you, your suggestions really helped. Added an answer  of what fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a dependency, which had `application.xml` in it's resources. In my case that was a legacy dependency and it was not used anywhere so the fix was just to remove it. In case that dependency was required, the solution would probably be to somehow exclude that `application.xml` loading as Spring boot config file.

Comment: I have the same problem but in this case I can not eliminate it because it is the ear deployment descriptor. Why should I be trying to load this file found in / META-INF?

Comment: @JoseLuque , not sure I understand your issue completely. Could you explain in more details?

Comment: I exposed the problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/85103469?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

The essayist is to create new Spring Boot project using https://start.spring.io/ and then migrate your code.

Everything else is much more work.

Answer (score 1):

JDK: 1.8
Spring Boot: 2.1.4-RELEASE

@Adomas I met this situation just now. The reason is that I have a dependency jar which includes the file named 'application.xml' in the classpath.

After I remove this file 'application.xml' from this dependency jar, I had solved this problem.

```
22:20:52.866 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.xml'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:556)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:502)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:469)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$6(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:450)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:449)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:446)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:192)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.xxx.Application.main(Application.java:16)
Caused by: java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 33; 文档根元素 "beans" 必须匹配 DOCTYPE 根 "null"。
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.load(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:80)
    at java.util.Properties$XmlSupport.load(Properties.java:1201)
    at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:881)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:137)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.loadProperties(PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.load(PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:574)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:528)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 文档根元素 "beans" 必须匹配 DOCTYPE 根 "null"。
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1599)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1877)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1289)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.getLoadingDoc(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:106)
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.load(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:78)
    ... 31 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Correct, mine solution was basically the same, as mentioned in my answer above.

Answer (score -1):

I had issue with `1.5.9.RELEASE` version

> [Error: Could not find or load main class ... in Spring Boot 1.5.9 version but not in 1.4.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627117/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-spring-boot-1-5-9-version-but-no)

I currently use the `1.4.7.RELEASE`. I would suggest you to try to update your spring dependency to this version

```
parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Suggestion to downgrade to another major version is hardly a solution.

Comment: really? What will you do if the latest version has a defect that is not fixed? wait

Comment: Use the previous minor that works NOT the previous major... Nonetheless it isn't the answer to this specific question as something is triggering the load of a J2EE application deployment descriptor.

Comment: So what is the minor for 1.5.9 version?

Comment: my suggestion was based on this start.spring.io which does not give minor major. I tried to help with the one which is working.

Answer (score -1):

Spring Boot try to load "application.xml", "application.properties" and "application.yml" at "classpath:/". If you want to override the "application.xml", you need to use a valid xml. Like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" standalone = "yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE dummy [ <!ELEMENT dummy (dummy?) > ]>
<dummy><dummy></dummy></dummy>
```